# Capture downloading link with ADB

Tags: android, adb

I'm able to list apps downloading in Android, with:

```sh
adb shell dumpsys activity services | findstr download
```

Which results:

```
  * ServiceRecord{a312ba3 u0 org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.fenix.downloads.DownloadService}
    intent={cmp=org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.fenix.downloads.DownloadService}
    isForeground=true foregroundId=100 foregroundNoti=Notification(channel=mozac.feature.downloads.generic shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x262 color=0xff607d8b groupKey=mozac.feature.downloads.group vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0)
```

What's the command to actuall get the URL or Link that is currently being downloaded?

Comment: And also how to get the link or URL of failed downloads

Comment: Most likely, there is none.